# Java turn a string into a variable?

Tags: java, string

Is it possible for a method to get a `string` and turn that `string` into a variable? Such as:

```
x1 = new X();
x2 = new X();
x3 = new X();

public void doThis(String y)
{
   y.doSomething();
}
```

where `y` is x1, x2, or x3?
So the method is actually `x1.doSomething()`; or so on?

Comment: Cant understand your question :(

Comment: You could implement your own serialization of X into a String then you'll deserialize it in doThis method. Honestly this doesnt look good, you could refactor / redesign your code.

Comment: In general this is bad, bad, bad practice.  There is almost a better way to do it that will be more secure, clean, safe, idiomatic, transparent, readable, faster, and better on performance.

Answer (score 3):

No. There's no way of doing it in Java, and *wanting* to do it indicates that you probably really want a collection of some kind.

If you've got a collection of values which you want to identify by contiguous integers, ideally starting at 0, then use an array or a `List<T>`. If you've got a collection of values which you really want to identify by string (e.g. because you'll have `x` and `y` rather than `1` and `2`) then use a `Map<String, Foo>` (where `Foo` is the type of value you want to map to).

Answer (score -1):

```
public void doThis(Object y)
   {
   y.doSomething();
   }
```

This is what you should be doing. or you could just have a if-else or case statement and decide what method to call.

Answer (score -1):

you can create no variable from string, but you can create class instance dynamically from string.
e.g

```
NewClassInterface x;

public void doThis(String y)
{
 x= Class.forName(y).newInstance();
 x.doSomething();
}
```

obviously, you must already have NewClass implementation anywhere.

hope this help